# How can I figure out if the current item is the last item in a section of a ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

So when I am drawing my `ListView` items I am sorting them into sections. Each item in a section has a line as a separator from the next item. For the last item I don't want to draw this separator. How can I figure out if the current item which is drawing itself, is the last item in the section (not in the `ListView`!)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently `ListView` has attached properties called `section`,`previousSection`,`nextSection`. With these it is pretty easy to find out if the next or previous section is the same as the current section. If it is not the same, then it means it is the last item in the section.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it is possible to figure that out. However, it might be possible to achieve the same result in a different way. Instead of each item having a line separating it from the next item have a line separating it from the previous item, have that in the section delegate as well and simply don't draw it for the item where `index === 0`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately in this case my 2nd section (and so on) will have a line below it, because the `index` doesn't changes to 0 after each section.

Comment: @Silex - you could extend the section delegate to overlap the item below it and hide the line. It will certainly be easier than something like a manual implementation of sections using a listview of listviews

Comment: Yea, was thinking of something like that...gonna try it, but sounds a bit ugly solution. :)

Comment: My first idea was using a footer to hide the last line by modifying its z value to cover the last item, alas the footer will not be instantiated after the last item, but will occupy the end of the view itself, so it will not work if the view content is taller than the view itself. So moving the line to the top and hiding it with the section delegate is the only easy solution. Yes it is ugly, but QML's components design often doesn't fit every need, so it is either ugly fixes or lengthy reimplementations, take your pick.

Comment: Your suggestion by covering it up actually works pretty nicely so for now I gonna go with it, thanks again!

Comment: I find a way to figure it out in a nicer way, see my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each delegate item knows its own index so it can compare it against the `ListView` item count:

```
ListView {
    id: theListView
    model: ...
    delegate: Item {
        property bool isLast: index+1 < theListView.count ? false : true
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**index == 0** shows the first(actually the latest) item of the model if the model is static and not dynamic. That means that if your listView is updated with the new items every now and then, then index == 0  gets bound to different element when the a new list item arrives.